# Elisp revert add-face-text-property

Tags: elisp, faces

I start with this:

```
(setq test (propertize "foobar" 'face 'font-lock-keyword-face))
;;=> #("foobar" 0 6 (face font-lock-keyword-face))
(add-face-text-property 0 3 'font-lock-type-face nil test)
test
;;=> 
;; #("foobar"
;;   0 3 (face (font-lock-type-face font-lock-keyword-face))
;;   3 6 (face font-lock-keyword-face))
```

Now I'd like to remove `font-lock-type-face` in the whole string,
while preserving `font-lock-keyword-face` and all other possible
faces.

What's an easy way to do this?

Comment: You could add an attribute that is an alias to `face` and use to to set `font-lock-type-face` (font-lock does something similar with the relatively unknown property `font-lock-face`). If you do that, it would be trivial to remove it. (Of course, this might not match your use case at all.)

Comment: What @Lindydancer said. Or if you don't need to do this a lot or in a general way, them maybe (?): (1) just `(put-text-property 0 6 'face 'font-lock-keyword-face test)` ;-) or (2) use `get-text-property` to get the full `face` property, then remove `font-lock-type-face` from it, and set that value for the string. AFAIK, there is not a handy function for doing what you ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `font-lock--remove-face-from-text-property`, tho as the "--" indicates, this is not really meant to be used.